# Jquery, get text of each div created in foreach loop in asp.net core?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working on a `Asp.net core` project and in my `index.cshtml` view, i have something like this

**index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<jquery.Models.Comment>

<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <ul style="list-style:none;">
            <li>
                <button class="btn btn-success"  id="btnlike">
                @item.LikeCount
            </button>

            <div id="cmid">@item.Id</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
}
</div>


@section Scripts{
<script>
    $(document).delegate('#btnlike', 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var post_data = $('#cmid').text();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Like", "Home")',
            data: { 'cid': post_data }
        })
    });
</script>
}
```

In my `index` view there is a `foreach` loop that creates some `li` and each `li` contains a `button`. I want to click on any button to post `@item.id` exactly the same to the `HomeController` and `Like` Action.
But now click on any button, only the first `id` of the `div` is posted to the `controller` And `cid` parameter in `Like` Action is 1 .

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new List<Comment>
        {
            new Comment {Id = 1,LikeCount = 5},
            new Comment {Id = 2,LikeCount =15},
            new Comment {Id = 3, LikeCount = 20},
            new Comment {Id = 4, LikeCount = 14},
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Like(int cid)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**Comment Model**

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int LikeCount { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You cannot repeat the div and button IDs over and over in the foreach loop as ids need to be unique.  Apply a class to the repeated div and button instead and use `$(".className")` notation in jQuery rather than `$("#idName")` notation

Comment: @Tommy But when i add class to `button` get first id again. And if i add class to `div` with `@item.Id` get all ids in all div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned above, you cannot duplicate Ids...

Why not give a try to another approach:

```
@model IEnumerable<jquery.Models.Comment>

<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <ul style="list-style:none;">
            <li>
                <button class="btn btn-success"  onclick="submitPost(@item.Id)">
                @item.LikeCount
            </button>

            <div id="cmid">@item.Id</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
}
</div>


@section Scripts{
<script>
    function submitPost(postId)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Like", "Home")',
            data: { cid: postId }
        });
    }
</script>
}
```